# Can we add options to closing questions as off-topic when the question belongs on another SE site besides our own Meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Many questions asked on Phil SE seem to be better fits for other SE sites, e.g. Math, Physics, Biology, Cognitive Sciences, History, Law, Skeptics, sometimes even Sci-Fi/Fantasy or Worldbuilding. However, when voting to close as off-topic and choosing "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" as the reason the only option given in the next screen's menu is our own Meta. I checked on other SE sites, and some list multiple options in the same menu. Of course, one can choose "While this question may be related to philosophy...", which is what usually happens, and write recommended alternative in the comments, but this is less specific/constructive, and closers often forego commenting. Is there a way to add other options?

Comment: Definitely possible and a great suggestion... to add close list items it takes two mods. so i'll need to coordinate with Joseph, Stoic, or MixedMath.

Comment: That's weird, I get the full list! --But I'm pretty sure I only see a limited list on sites where I'm not ♦, so maybe it's an intended limitation?

Comment: We had 9 outgoing migrations in the last 90 days, and 3 were rejected - are you sure this is necessary? My experience on other sites is that extra sites are added when it's clear that there is need for it. The recommended alternative is to flag the post for moderator attention. That way, if the question is migrated, it will end up in the stats, and we can make informed decisions as to what sites should appear in the list.

Comment: @Keelan I just had the issue with this one http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/31663/how-many-mersenne-primes-will-ever-be-written-down and a couple of times in the last two weeks. I think it might help with potential new users since it might feel like less of a spurn to them (such feelings do arise as comment threads attest), and I do not see how it can hurt. It does not preclude more complex alternatives, just provides a more convenient default. It may even make more people comfortable with closing under such reason.

Comment: The potential problem is that the migrations aren't screened. When added to the list, if 4 or 5 3K+ users vote to migrate a question it will be migrated. With the current scheme, this is possible for moderators only. I sometimes see votes to migrate questions to Meta, while the questions are clearly non-meta, showing that some 3K+ users don't understand the scheme. So, I'm not sure other communities will be happy if we remove this barrier.

Comment: I'm not advocating against this. I'm just pointing out the potential problem and my experience with how this decision is made on other SE sites. I personally would suggest flagging these questions for moderator attention now (to request a migration), and come back when from the statistics is clear that the community would benefit from this.

Comment: I think this is a good idea but should be mixed with some better guide rails for how to ask problem question types. I can think of three: philosophy of science questions which interweave (often bad) science with philosophy, philosophy of religion questions which interweave doctrinal issues (both Christianity, Islam, and antagonism to them), and philosophy of math questions that say mathematically outlandish things -- [I'm looking at you uses of "infinity"]

Comment: @Keelan Do I understand correctly that five people giving this reason will cause automatic migration? What I thought it would do is simply display a different message after "The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:" rather than automatically migrate. It will then be up to the poster and/or moderator to initiate the migration. If it automatically migrates that is odd since the phrase says nothing about migration.  Can that be blocked? Other closing options do not induce automatic actionsm, can we add such non-automatic option with a list separately?

Comment: I'm back at a computer and could do some better research. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79961/205264) is a Meta.SE post as reference for my earlier comment. In response to your question: yes, five people giving this reason will cause automatic migration. I can't find reference for it now, but I vaguely remember that when there are 4 votes pro migration and 1 contra, it is still migrated. Not sure on that though.